# Django - get value of readonly field (fix readonly error)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to edit fieldset.html template in order to add the hidden input under readonly div (in readonly case).

```
{% if field.is_readonly %}
  <div class="readonly {% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}">{{ field.contents }}</div>
  <input id="{% if field.field.name %} id-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}" type="hidden" value="{{ field.field.initial }}"/>
{% else %}
  {{ field.field }}
{% endif %}
```

My problem is that if I set a field readonly with "get_readonly_fields", I can't submit the form because hidden field is required (I think this is a big error of django that uses div instead of the hidden input).

I tried to fix it with the code above but I'am not able to insert the value in to my field, because "field.field.initial" is empty for readonly field. How can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

My form.py:

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  val1 = forms.CharField()
  val2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(groups__name='Group1'))
  val3 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

  class Meta: 
    model  = MyModel
    fields = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        attrs = {'class':'form-control'}
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update(attrs)
```

My admin.py

```
class CampaignAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    return MyModelAdminForm

  def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    return [
      (None,           {'fields': ['val1', 'val2']}),
      ('Informations', {'fields': ['val3']}),
    ]

  def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
      return self.readonly_fields + ('val2',)
    else:
      return self.readonly_fields
```

I need that val2 is in readonly mode in edit page.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can add any fields to your form as you see fit. So, if you need the field to show up as read-only as well as a hidden field, you can just add two fields. You should name the hidden field correctly so that saving works. You can use `label` to change the label of the read-only field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#label).

EDIT - solution for your code:

For your solution, if you change the form to have `val2` as readonly field instead of a regular field, you also need to change the form's `Meta.fields` setting from:

```
fields = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

to

```
fields = ('val1', 'val3')
```

Otherwise, the validators for `val2` will run.

Or, you have to change the widget of `val2` to `HiddenInput` and add its value as `readonly_field` using a different name with an explicit method in your django admin class. But that would require changing the fieldsets depending on the mode (edit or create).